# Memory efficient list for android

Tags: android

I have a list of about 100 items. In each list item I need a framelayout with 2 relative layouts. When a button called "Flip" is clicked then one relative layout will flip out and the other relative layout will flip in. And each item has full width of the screen. So, I need to show the item in a horizontal scroll view. Now, I want to keep at most 3 items every moment. When user scrolls to the first item then we have to update the 3 items. The first item will be the 2nd item. And we have to add another item at the front. In this way we have to update the items when user scrolls to the last item. I have tried many ways. I have used Gallery for the horizontal scroll view. And used the onItemSelected method. But, if I scroll the Gallery fast then it crashes. So, please someone help me to implement the 3 items idea.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a `ListView`. Is there a reason you are trying to reinvent it?

Also don't you mean a vertical scroll view? Why are using a horizontal?

Comment: No, I don't need a vertical scroll view. I need a horizontal scrollview like Gallery.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please edit it and add screen shots to describe your layout, and re-think your delivery, it is too long and ambiguous